# Is it possible to load custom cells in a UICollectionView at the same time the view loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new to iOS and I seem to get stuck on a UICollectionView problem.

I'm trying to make a tab bar app whose first tab is a navigation controller that includes a collection view. The content for the customs cells (images, texts) come from web services. Since it takes time for contents over web services to be downloaded, I want the cells to be presented as soon as the app fires up without having to wait for data to be loaded (**which means before data are loaded**). So there will be a short amount of time when there are **only empty cells** (& tab bar & nav bar) on the screen.

**However, when my app runs, the cells are created at the same time that all the data are loaded from web services. Sometimes when internet speed is slow, there is a long time when nothing is on the screen before cells with data are loaded.** I wonder if someone can tell me what I did wrong. Thank you so much in advance!

Here's the code for my viewDidLoad: method in collection view controller implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                                             collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];

    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 10, 5);
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5;

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TDEFeedCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"feedCell"];

}
```

Should I do the above implementation in `loadView:` method instead and assign a configured `UICollectionView` object to the collection view controller's `view` property so that cells would load as soon as the `loadView:` method is called?

Thank you very much!

--- edit ---
Here's the implementation of the controller's initializer:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
{
    self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    if (self) {
    self.navigationItem.title = @"News Feeds";

    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
                                             delegate:nil
                                        delegateQueue:nil];
    [self fetchFeed];
    }
return self;
}
```

Here's the implementation of `-(void)fetchFeed` method used in the initializer:

```
- (void)fetchFeed
{
    NSString *requestString = @"http://exampleapi.exampleweb.com/feeds.json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                                                     completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                                   error:nil];

                                      self.feeds = jsonObject[@"feeds"];

                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                          [self.collectionView reloadData];
                                      });
                                  }];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

In data source methods, I simply used JSON data parsed in `-(void)fetchFeed` method and assign them to appropriate cell views.

Comment: If you want to present the `self.collectionView` after the download is done, you can achieve that by setting the alpha of `self.collectionView` to 0 and set it to 1 after the download is complete, as an example.

Comment: Hi Gyfis! Thank you very much for you reply! I actually wanted the cells to be presented as soon as the app fires up without having to wait for web data to be loaded. How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: How/where are you fetching the data to show in your cells?

Comment: Do you want to present some placeholder content while the fetch happens?  Will you know the count of the objects being retrieved?  Or do you want to present nothing on the very first launch, then after that present whatever the query result was from the last query?  Whatever you decide to do, viewDidLoad is fine.  (As the name implies, it gets called *after* the view is loaded, not during).

Comment: Hi Philip Mills and Danh! Thank you for your replies! I've updated my question. I've included my initializer and a relevant custom method's implementation. When internet speed gets slow, there can be a long time when nothing is on the screen before cells with data are loaded. I want to present empty cells on the very first launch, and then present query result from web services.

Comment: Have you tried using - [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) and [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry ArenLi, I completely misunderstood the question.

The solution you want (I think) is to have the `self.feeds` pre-filled by some blank data before the download is complete, and when it completes, you update the array and reload the `self.collectionView`.

Try to add this

```
self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; // or any other number you want
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

after

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TDEFeedCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"feedCell"];
```

in the `- viewDidLoad` method, and see if it helps.

The problem is of course in the fact that you don't know the number of cells to present before the download is complete, so you have to either guess or just settle with some arbitrary number.

**NOTE:** Be careful with this approach as it might crash, because the cells might expect to find some data in the `self.feeds`. You need to make sure the cells are prepared to get blank data instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a photo grid view sample project that loads the assets on-the-fly with smart caching.

[Example app using Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575)

If I were you I would consider starting with that, then it should be trivial to replace the photo lib calls with your own web service calls.

This project gives you a lot for free - trust me I pretty much wrote something similar from scratch before I had come across this page.

Comment: Hi Jeshua! Thanks for your reply! My contents are purely from internet. I want to present empty cells on the very first launch, and then present query result from web services. However, with my current implementation, there could be a long time when nothing (no cell) is on the screen before contents from web server is loaded. How can I present empty cells right at launch? Thank you!

Comment: If you base your solution on the cited sample project, you can immediately present your empty grid view and as data comes in populate your cells. Apple's example works with networked images (iCloud), so you can leverage that to your needs.